# Regex and PHP - how to match with ignoring pattern parts

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this string:

```
Hello, world
```

My goal is to use the `preg_match` function from PHP to end up with:

```
array(
      [0] => Hello
      [1] => world
)
```

This is just an example. I know that I can use explode, or any other method, but it is mandatory for me to use `preg_match` to match a sub-string followed by a comma, followed by another sub-string while ignoring the comma in the matched result.

Thank you.

Comment: @Adam. as I tryed to mention, only preg match can be used. Did you read my question?

Comment: At the absolute most basic level `/^(\w+),\s(\w+)$/` will save the first word to the *$1* match and the second to the *$2* match.

Comment: You can try: `[a-zA-Z]+?(?=,\s+|$)`.

Comment: You say "it is mandatory for me to use preg_match to match a sub-string followed by a comma".  Why?  Is this homework?  If so, what other constraints are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do:

```
$str = 'Hello, world';
preg_match('/^([^,]+),([^,]+)$/', $str, $matches);
```

I suggest you to have a look at the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about php, but you can do simply:

```
/\w+/
```

That will match `hello` and `world`